# Wix Toolset - Is there a way to set a property based on RadioButtonGroup value within the control?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

What I'd like to do is to set, or alternatively unset, a property (CREATE_USER) based on a selected RadioButton within a RadioButtonGroup control.  Is this possible?

Note: The example below does NOT work for me.

```
# Placed under Fragment tag
<Property Id="SQL_USER_TYPE" Value="ExistingSqlUser" />

# Placed under Dialog tag
<Control Id="SqlUserType" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="40" Y="134" Width="210" Height="15" Property="SQL_USER_TYPE">
    <RadioButtonGroup Property="SQL_USER_TYPE">
        <RadioButton Value="NewSqlUser" X="90" Y="0" Width="80" Height="15" Text="!(loc.TenantDBConnectDlg_CreateNewUser)" />
        <RadioButton Value="ExistingSqlUser" X="0" Y="0" Width="80" Height="15" Text="!(loc.TenantDBConnectDlg_UseExistingUser)" />
    </RadioButtonGroup>
    <Publish Property="CREATE_USER" Value="1">SQL_USER_TYPE = "NewSqlUser"</Publish>
    <Publish Property="CREATE_USER" Value="{}">SQL_USER_TYPE = "ExistingSqlUser"</Publish>
</Control>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the Publish elements on the Next button of the dialog with a higher or schedule them as set property custom actions in the execute sequence.  It depends on your silent installation story and when/what you are doing with the property.  Remember in silent install UI sequence isn't processed.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have these Publish elements fire whenever a user selects a RadioButton element option.  In looking through the install log file, I don't see that these Publish elements have ever fired.  The value of SQL_USER_TYPE changes, but not the value of CREATE_USER.  Is there any way to get a Publish element to fire under a RadioButtonGroup Control element?

Comment: Not all windows installer controls support ControlEvents.

Comment: see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370958(v=vs.85).aspx
"RadioButtonGroup controls only set property values and cannot be used to send a ControlEvent."

Comment: BTW, make sure you understand the relationship between WiX and MSI.   WiX is a language to transform, build an MSI database.  There is no such thing as a RadioButton element for a user to select.  The element is merely an abstraction for the underlying Windows Installer Control and ControlEvent types.

Comment: That's what I was seeing but I had been unable to confirm this.  Thanks for the confirmation.  This will help me better make WiX coding decisions in the future.